# Jacoco with jmockit causing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: jacoco, jmockit

I have recently upgraded my project to java 17,
as part of it i upgraded jacoco version to 0.8.8 and jmockit to 1.49 and all the test cases pass,

but while creating jacoco test report the same test cases are failing with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2308 out of bounds for length 1060

at the lines where we use

```
 new MockUp<>() {
 };
```

could someone tell me, what can be wrong in this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JMockit doesn't fully support all Java 11+ features for already 4 years - see https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/615#issuecomment-501009439

Comment: Thanks Godin for commenting, yes and that is why we are migrating from jmockit to mockito, but in mockito also we are facing issues like for mocking static methods we had to add mockito-inline and due to that non static mocks are not getting mocked.